# Unable to load default profile in Chrome with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to do something on a page that requires http authentication.

I am already login in my default profile. But the selenium chromedriver will automatically use a new profile for each use therefore I can't get past the authentication stage.

Therefore, I was thinking of using my default profile (With account login inside) on Selenium WebDriver for Chrome.

The default profile don't seem to be loaded into Chrome even when I use the code as below

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");   


IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\selenium-dotnet-2.33.0\net40",options);
```

Any help? =)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630091/using-the-same-chrome-profile-session-for-different-chromedriver-instances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add '--' before your Chrome switch and remove `Default` from path, escape slashes if necessary.

```
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
```

Comment: Hi there. I tried adding the '--' before the Chrome switch. It did not work sadly.

Comment: Hi @user1177637 I just tried the updated code. It's still not working. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @LawrenceWong: Please explain what does `not working` mean? Also make sure your path is actually correct.

Comment: Hi user1177636, I just realised I forgot to change the user_name part to my profile name. Thanks! It's working now. =)

Comment: Hi @YiZeng , tried this,chrome opens with the user profile but gives this error {"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52408/session timed out after 60 seconds."}

Comment: @Gokul: Hello. This answer was made 4 years ago, ChromDriver has been changed quite a bit. Maybe create a little demo to reproduce your problem and get help there https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help