# Chrome browsing windows stays open even after session failed with WebDriverException

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am using selenium 3.141.59 with chrome 79 and chromedriver 79. Randomly I am getting an exception from `RemoteWebDriver.get(url);` and that session removing from the selenium server. But the Chrome window stays open. Because of that, I am not able to create new sessions with the same user directory. On my every attempt to create a new session, chrome window opens but session creation fails. So those All open Chrome windows causing memory leak! I tried to set timeout and browserTimeout from the server but it didn't help. Any idea what's happening?

I am starting server by:

```
java -jar -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=ALL selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -timeout 250 -browserTimeout 300
```

The exception I am getting randomly:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: 'myip', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.154-128.181.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: mypackage.SeleniumHelper$2
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: /var/tmp/username...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:35341}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 66ddc30a30affc4ba52a539bc41...}
Session ID: 66ddc30a30affc4ba52a539bc411ac2c
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1082.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:?]
        ... 65 more
```

My chrome options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();
options.addArguments ("user-data-dir=/var/tmp/username");
options.addArguments ("disable-gpu");
options.addArguments ("disable-impl-side-painting");
options.addArguments ("disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments ("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments ("disable-gpu-sandbox");
options.addArguments ("no-sandbox");
options.addArguments ("disable-accelerated-2d-canvas");
options.addArguments ("disable-accelerated-jpeg-decoding");
options.addArguments ("test-type=ui");
options.addArguments ("no-proxy-server");
```

Comment: How is `userDataDir` defined?

Comment: let's say it is `/var/tmp/username` all the time.

Comment: what if you use a try and except function, where in except, you let the driver close chrome and reopen it again to create a new session?

Comment: Actually I am calling driver.close() and driver.quit() if the exception occurs. But it is not closing Chrome windows.

Comment: It is like selenium server loses its control on the Chrome window. I see in the server log "removing session blabla" but Chrome window stays open.

Comment: and a reopen? I'll post a python code as an anwer, in the comments I can't post the correct code.

Comment: We need more detail here. Especially how you are running your code. I woul imagine you codes gets an exception somewhere along the way and never reaches to  `driver.close()` part. This is obviously just a wild guess. We need to see the code to be able to help. GZood luck!

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider a few things:

- [--user-data-dir](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#user-data-dir): Refers to the [directory](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc?q=kUserDataDir&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=106) where the browser stores the user profile. So you can't pass any arbitrary value. See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585508/how-to-initiate-a-new-chrome-session-when-the-default-session-is-already-running/60048530#60048530) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre/60048564#60048564) discussion.
- [--disable-gpu](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-gpu-sandbox): [Disables GPU hardware acceleration](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=kDisableGpu&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=144). If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch. However the purpose of the argument `--disable-gpu` was to enable [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) platform.  It was needed as [*SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) earlier. As you are on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) *os* you need to remove it. See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724) discussion.
- Ideally, you only add the arguments which are mandatory as per your *Test Specifications*.
- Sample minimum code block:

  ```
  public class A_Chrome 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, when your program raises an exception, the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance looses the control of the *Browsing Context* and both turns into a [Zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). Hence [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) window stays open.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will try and post the results!

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a try and except function? Where in except, you let the driver close chrome and reopen it again to create a new session?

```
     try:
       #set your try code here
     except TimeoutException:
       print('Page took too long to load or there was a different problem :(')
       driver.quit()
          try:
            #set your new code here
          except:
            #set your except here
```

Or you could try to open an new chrome window after the except

Comment: Unfortunately, driver not able to close Chrome in that situation. I have no idea why!