# Selenium Chrome Driver : user data directory is already in use

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For this same error there are many questions in Stackoverflow. But none of them solved my problem. So I have to post this again.

My Code:

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Chrome\Profile 6");
            options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Profile 6");
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
```

Initially I was getting an error `" Unable to move cache folder, access denied."` 
then I have added the line `options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");` and the error is gone.

Now my Code is opening the browser with profile : "Profile 6". But after that its throwing the error
Error in the line : `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

*"Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
"*

I have already read almost all topics related to this error. Few of them are :

[How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium)

[InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error using --user-data-dir to start Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987080/invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-user-data-directory-is-alre)

[How to initiate a new Chrome session when the default session is already running using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585508/how-to-initiate-a-new-chrome-session-when-the-default-session-is-already-running)

I am stuck in this problem for more than a week now. Please help.

**EDIT:**
To confirm that I am not using the already opened default user profile, I checked `Cheome://version` to confirm the user data directory path. Its different than the default.

Also I tried to to run the code after closing all the open chrome instances. This Time I have not received the error. The browser opened by the webdriver. But after that nothing happened. The code got time out error after 60 seconds in the line :  `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Comment: you sure the roaming directory contains your current user's profile directory?

Comment: Yes I checked that. I have edited my question. Please check. I have 3 years of Selenium experience. I never faced this before. I am really frustrated now.

Comment: does your default profile path say it's in the roaming directory?  This info is usually shared across all users... I think when Chrome starts, it grabs data from roaming and applies it to the current user's profile.  You don't need to set that path.

Comment: Yes My Default profile path is in roaming directory.
I tried with not setting the path. Still same error.

Comment: if you comment out the options lines setting profile paths, does it work or are you seeing the same timeout?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question removing --disable-gpu is giving error : Unable to move cache folder, access denied. Removing --disable-extensions is giving error while running the code with out any existing chrome instance.

Comment: I'm curious if it runs OK without these lines: options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Chrome\Profile 6");
            options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Profile 6");  If it does not I wouldn't run as a roaming user.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are specifying the wrong directory. Instead of:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Chrome\Profile 6
```

You need to pass:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Chrome\Profile 6
```

So the effective line of code will be:

```
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Chrome\Profile 6");
```

---

### Update 1

Additionally, you can remove the argument `--profile-directory` as in:

```
options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Profile 6");
```

---

### Update 2

*If I close all the chrome instances and run the code, I am not getting this error* means ChromeDriver is able to open the *Chrome* browsing instance perfectly. But to analyze why *nothing happened* can be interpreted from the *TRACE* level logs.

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My chrome://version/ says the Profile Path is C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Chrome\Profile 6.
 
However I see the /AppData/Local folder also have user profiles. So I tried with your option. But getting same eror.

Comment: @Arijit Check out the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: After removing the --profile-directory, The chrome is opening with the default user profile and I'm getting same error.  Please check the last edit of my question. If I close all the chrome instances and run the code, I am not getting this error. one instance of chrome is opening perfectly by the webdriver. But the URL is not opening. and the code is getting time out error after 60 seconds.

Comment: @Arijit Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I'm using C#. my selenium and chrome driver nuget packages are latest.