# C# fill web form / scratch web page using the current profile / session

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, firefox-profile, chrome-profile

I'm trying to play with web forms / loggins, etc. and for this I need to start the browser (chrome, for example) with the **current user profile session**. I found 2 possible ways of doing this, but I can't finish the code for both of them :)

**Solution 1**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

This will open a new tab in current session with my user profile (perfect!). But what now? I don't have a variable like "browser" to find elements by id, or something like that. Is there anything I can do next to get the control of the page / browser?

**Solution 2 (selenium driver)**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");
g.webdriver[0] = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

a) If I don't use the argument user-data-dir with the path for my user profile, it will open with no errors (default selenium chrome session) and I'll need to log in on my desired web page -> not a good idea for Enterprise stuff.
b) Using this code it will open a new chrome browser window with my current session / user profile (perfect!), but the code will fail with the error "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist", this means I won't be able to continue and do my stuff. I also tried a lot of things like:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"C:\Users\john\.nuget\packages\selenium.chrome.webdriver\2.45.0\driver\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");

options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArguments("--no-cache");

options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);

g.webdriver[0] = new ChromeDriver(options);
g.webdriver[0].Manage().Window.Maximize();
g.webdriver[0].Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The only way I know where you can "easy" control a form of a webpage is with the default web browser of WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back and I FOUND THE SOLUTION! (thanks to this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630091/using-the-same-chrome-profile-session-for-different-chromedriver-instances?rq=1))

With the below code you can create NEW PROFILES and reuse them. If you will log in once with the desired accounts (for example your google account), it will remain synchronized! So it's awesome for whatever you need to use it for.

Requirements: Selenium.WebDriver (NuGet) + chromedriver_win32 (version compatible for your chrome version-manually download) + edit in code the "default_profile_dir" and the "chromedriver_path"
C# web forms, all code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Management;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;

namespace ChromeAssistant
{
    public partial class form_main_chromeassistant : Form
    {
        public form_main_chromeassistant()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_test_profile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoreDriver CD = new CoreDriver();

            //Config
            CD.my_port = 50150;
            CD.my_name = "ChromeAssistant";
            CD.ConfigureProfile();
            CD.Initialize();

            CD.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ro/");
        }
    }

    #region CoreDriver
    public class CoreDriver
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;
        public string my_name { get; set; }
        public int my_port { get; set; }

        public string default_profile_dir = @"C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\";
        public string chromedriver_path = @"C:\Users\john\.nuget\packages\chromedriver_win32\";
        public string site_profile_path;
        public string site_profile_path_s;
        public string default_path;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
            options.AddArgument("--test-type");
            options.AddArgument("--silent");
            options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=" + site_profile_path_s);
            options.AddArgument("--disable-plugins"); // disable flash

            var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(chromedriver_path);
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driverService.Port = my_port;

            driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

            //The 2 line were commented by me because I got 2 errors for them
            //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 14));
            //driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            //This was added by me to replace the 2 commented lines
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);

            IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            jscript.ExecuteScript("return window.stop");
        }

        public void ConfigureProfile()
        {
            site_profile_path_s = default_profile_dir + "profile " + my_name;
            site_profile_path = site_profile_path_s + @"\Default";

            default_path = default_profile_dir + @"User Data\Default";

            if (!Directory.Exists(site_profile_path))
            {
                CreateBlankProfile();
            }
            else
            {
                // copy existing chrome profile. Keep cache, extensions, etc.
                CopyProfileFiles();

                // but stay away from opened tabs
                RemoveOpenedTabsFiles();
            }

        }

        public void CleanUpOldProfiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(default_profile_dir);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("profile*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (directories.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var folder in directories)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(folder.FullName, true);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        public void CreateBlankProfile()
        {
            // new profile direftory
            CreateIfMissing();

            // copy existing chrome profile. Keep cache, extensions, etc.
            // but stay away from opened tabs
            CopyProfileFiles();
            CopyProfileFolders();
        }

        public void CopyProfileFiles()
        {
            // default profile location
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(default_path);

            // copy files
            List<string> file_lib = new List<string>() { "Cookies", "Login", "Preferences", "Secur" };
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (files.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (PassFileOrFolder(file.Name, file_lib))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(site_profile_path + @"\" + file.Name, true);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        public void RemoveOpenedTabsFiles()
        {
            // default profile location
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(site_profile_path);

            // copy files
            List<string> file_lib = new List<string>() { "Current", "Last" };
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (files.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (PassFileOrFolder(file.Name, file_lib))
                    {
                        File.Delete(file.FullName);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        public void CopyProfileFolders()
        {
            // default profile location
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(default_path);

            // copy folders
            List<string> folder_lib = new List<string>() { "databases", "Extension", " Storage", "Web Applications", "File System", "IndexedDB" };
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (directories.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var folder in directories)
                {
                    if (PassFileOrFolder(folder.Name, folder_lib))
                    {
                        DirectoryCopy(folder.FullName, site_profile_path + @"\" + folder.Name, true);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        private void CreateIfMissing()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(site_profile_path);
        }

        private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                    + sourceDirName);
            }

            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
            }

            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool PassFileOrFolder(string input, List<string> library)
        {
            foreach (string name in library)
            {
                if (input.Contains(name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```